# Keras image generator keep giving different number of labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generator

I am trying to make a simple fine turned Resnet50 model using the Market1501 dataset and keras.

So the data set contains images (12000 or so) and 751 labels that I want to use (0-750). I can fit the data into a single go so I have to use a image generator for this.

So my base model is like this

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3)))
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten(name="flatten")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(750, activation='softmax', name='fc8',kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.001))(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=x)
```

And my image generator is like this

```
def image_generator(image_array, batch_size):
    # Define data generator arguments
    datagen_args = dict(rotation_range=20,
                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                    shear_range=0.1,
                    zoom_range=0.1,
                    horizontal_flip=True)

    # Create different data generators for each image
    # This gives each image a unique transformation which will make it harder for the network
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**datagen_args)
    while True:
        number_of_images = len(image_array)
        indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(number_of_images))
        num_batches = number_of_images // batch_size
        for bid in range(num_batches):
            # loop once per batch
            images = []
            lables = []
            batch_indices = indices[bid * batch_size: (bid + 1) * batch_size]
            for i in batch_indices:
                img, lbl = image_array[i]
                # Process images
                img = image.load_img(os.path.join(TRAIN, img), target_size=[224, 224])
                img = image.img_to_array(img)
                #img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
                img = preprocess_input(img)
                img = datagen.random_transform(img)
                images.append(img)
                lables.append(lbl)
            yield np.array(images), to_categorical(lables)
```

And I use it like this

```
batch_size = 64
NUM_EPOCHS = 40
train_gen = image_generator(image_array, batch_size)
num_train_steps = len(image_array)
```

The issue is it give me this error

> Error when checking target: expected fc8 to have shape (751,) but got array with shape (742,)

And the bigger issue is the 2nd number keep changing so I know its something with the image generator not getting every label in for each iteration.

**EDIT**
How the data is generated:
There is a external list with the image and the label like this

```
['0002_451_03.jpg', '0']
img001.jpg, 0
img002.jpg, 0
...
img1500.jpg, 750
```

This is read in and loaded into a array. The label is the number after the image

Comment: Your labels are not coming from the ImageDataGenerator, they are external data passed to the function, so your question is unanswerable until you provide code that shows how that data is generated.

Comment: I edited it above to show how I am reading in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
batch_indices = indices[bid * batch_size: (bid + 1) * batch_size]
```

with

```
batch_indices = indices[bid * batch_size: min((bid + 1) * batch_size, number_of_images)]
```

Comment: give me a second let me try it. Thanks

Comment: can you explain a little bit What is min((bid + 1) * batch_size, number_of_images) for and what does it do